# Upload CSS file to blob storage with GZIP encoding

Tags: vb.net, azure, gzip, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to write a css file with GZIP encoding to Azure blob storage. The raw css is being pulled out of a textarea and passed in below as `ccsString`. The file is being written and I can veiw this in Azure Management Studio, when I try to view the css in Chrome it can't find the file (This web page is not available).

I'm clearly missing something obvious here but I can't see it?

```
Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("...")
Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
Dim container As CloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myContainer")

Dim blockBlob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("keyPath")
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = mimeType

Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ccsString)
Using memoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)
    Using gzip As New GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress)
       blockBlob.Properties.ContentEncoding = "gzip"
       blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream)
   End Using
End Using
```

**UPDATE --**

I have resolved this problem with the help of @Gaurav-Mantri. I'm also using [YUI Compressor](http://www.nuget.org/packages/yuicompressor.net/) (available as a NUGET package) to minify my css and javascript. Just look at the difference it makes! :)

[image]

Comment: Can you check the blob container ACL? It should be either `Blob` or `Pubic`.

Comment: The container is set to blob, other css files in the container can be viewed fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code (Sorry it's in C#):

```
    static void Gzip()
    {
        CloudBlobContainer container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("sotest");
        string dummyText = "This is a sample text which we need to compress using GZIP. This is a sample text which we need to compress using GZIP. This is a sample text which we need to compress using GZIP. This is a sample text which we need to compress using GZIP. This is a sample text which we need to compress using GZIP. ";
        dummyText += dummyText;
        dummyText += dummyText;
        dummyText += dummyText;
        dummyText += dummyText;
        dummyText += dummyText;
        dummyText += dummyText;
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("gzipcompressed.txt");
        blob.Properties.ContentEncoding = "gzip";
        blob.Properties.ContentType = "text/plain";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dummyText);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                gzip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            blob.UploadFromStream(ms);
        }
    }
```

Now coming to the issue:

I think your blob content is not getting gzip compressed at all. If I use your code and check the blob size, it's same as byte array size. Now the blob is not compressed and content encoding is set to GZIP so when Chrome tries to decompress it and it fails. I have had Chrome crash on me a number of times doing that.